# Unbinding/Rebinding .on()/.off() mouse events from animated buttons

Tags: jquery, button, mouseevent, slideshow

This question is somehow related to one other I posted before. The reason I'm making a new question is because I changed things a bit and haven't been able to deal with a litte issue since then.

So, I have this simple horizontal slideshow. I have a left and right button to control it (besides the ability to directly click on the slides). Basically I want my buttons to deactivate themselves when the slideshow reaches it's left/right end and reactivate when they are nedded again. I've tried with .off() but it just deactivates permanentely. When I want it back on - .on() - it doesn't work.

HTML markup:

```
<div id="rocksMenu_btnLeft"></div>
<div id="rocksMenu_btnRight"></div>

      <div id="centerArea">
         <div id="menuContainer">
            <div id="menuItem_1" class="menuItem">
               <div class="content">Contents1</div>
            </div>
            <div id="menuItem_2" class="menuItem">
               <div class="content">Contents2</div>
            </div>
            <div id="menuItem_3" class="menuItem">
               <div class="content">Contents3</div>
            </div>
            <div id="menuItem_4" class="menuItem">
               <div class="content">Contents4</div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
```

Full code here - [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p6Uxd/) (clean version - I deleted my button disabling code try, because it was getting messy).
I've searched for this issue, but couldn't get a clear answer.

Thanx.

Pedro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to deactivate the event, just do a check and if the end is reached, don't do the animation action.

```
$('#rocksMenu_btnRight').on('click', function() {
    if (menuItem_place === menuItem_limit) return;
    // animation code
}
```

For `btnLeft` just change the condition `if (menuItem_place === 0) return;`.

Comment: This is a better solution than unbinding the event.

Comment: @Pedro - the same way, check out this fiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/p6Uxd/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/p6Uxd/1/)

Comment: So simple. Brilliant. Thank you @Alexandrin Rus! :)

Comment: Not wanting to be abusive, but, how can I change the cursor? Disabled - cursor:default / Enabled - cursor:pointer? Before the return? Where? Thanx again.

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/p6Uxd/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/p6Uxd/4/) - in the mouseenter events you can verify the condition and change the cursor accordingly.