# Jquery document off mouseevent

Tags: jquery

Start

```
$(document).on('mousemove', "#id", EVENT);
```

Disable

```
$(document).off('mousemove', "#id");
```

I have tried...

```
$(document).off('mousemove', "#id", EVENT);
$("#id").unbind('mousemove');
```

Exact Functions

```
$(document).on('click', "#id", function (e) {
    $(document).on('mousemove', "#id", EVENT);
});

$(document).on('mouseup', function () {
    console.log('test');
    $(document).off('mousemove', "#id");
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This could be what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16019825/unbinding-rebinding-on-off-mouse-events-from-animated-buttons

Comment: Can you provide a demo on http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: because `mouseup` fires before `click` demo: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/92NHS/1/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [mousedown](http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/) instead of [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) since `click` is fired after `mouseup`

```
$(document).on('mousedown', "#id", function (e) {
    console.log('register')
    $(document).on('mousemove', "#id", EVENT);
});

$(document).on('mouseup', function () {
    console.log('test');
    $(document).off('mousemove', "#id", EVENT);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/92NHS/2/)

Comment: @Iscariot looking for a spec

Comment: I understand why, click is both parts of the event, up and down.  However, if a click is both up and down on an event, then the event should not fire until both requirements are met.

Comment: @Iscariot yes that what I also understood http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/click.html

Comment: I get what that says but click fires when just the mouse down requirement is met, not both.